# Completeness of measure (Folland 1.14)

Tags: measure-theory, outer-measure

Please forgive my (lack of) LaTeX. I am a bit confused by the matter of completeness in the first half of Prop 1.14 in Folland's Real Analysis. The setup is that we have a premeasure $\mu_0$ defined on an algebra $A$, and the claim is that there exists a measure $\mu$ on the $\sigma$-algebra $M(A)$ generated by that algebra, and that $\mu$ is equivalent to $\mu_0$ on $A$. It also mentions that this  is in fact ∗ (the outer measure induced by $_0$) restricted to $M(A)$.

Prop 1.13 shows that every set in the algebra $A$ on which a premeasure $\mu_0$ is defined is $\mu∗$-measurable by the outer measure $\mu∗$ induced by that $\mu_0$. It also shows that $\mu∗$ and $\mu_0$ agree on $A$.

Carathéodory's Theorem shows that an outer measure $\mu∗$ is complete on $M∗$, the $\sigma$-algebra of $\mu∗$-measurable sets. So please correct me where I am wrong:

Since every set in $A$ is $\mu∗$-measurable (1.13), then $M∗$ contains $M(A)$. Since $\mu∗$ is complete on $M∗$ (Carathéodory) then $\mu = \mu∗$ must be complete on $M(A)$ as well. Finally, since $\mu∗$ agrees with $\mu_0$ on $A$ (1.13), we have a measure $\mu$ on $M(A)$ that is equal to $\mu∗$ on $M(A)$, and whose restriction to $A$ is $\mu_0$, as claimed by 1.14 -- and this measure is complete on $M(A)$.

Sorry for the confusing wording. Folland does not state that the measure is complete, so have I made a mistake in my assumptions or reasoning? Thanks in advance for any replies

Comment: I have already read the post and replies found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2938856/understanding-pre-measures-and-extensions-of-measures-in-folland) but I can't follow the reply about exercise #22 in Ch.1 in order to see if it proves incompleteness.

Comment: What exactly is your question? Applying the Caratheodory condition to the outer measure $\mu^*$ induced by the premeasure $\mu_0$ gives you a $\sigma$-algebra $\mathscr M$ (which contains the algebra) on which $\mu^*$ is complete and whose restriction to the algebra agrees with $\mu_0$.

Comment: Sorry, my question is: Is the measure described in Prop 1.14 a complete measure on M(A)? Prop 1.14 claims existence of a measure on M(A) whose restriction to A is the premeasure, and that this measure is the outer measure on X restricted to M(A).

In the post I linked to in my comment above, a user replied that this measure as described is not necessarily complete, but my reasoning in my original post here seems to indicate that it must be complete as a consequence of Carathéodory and Prop. 1.13. So am I correct that it is complete, or have I missed something?

Comment: I don't know if I understood your question but let me try to help. Note that the term complete measure actually refers to the measure space. So, a measure is complete if every null set is measurable, that is, every null set is in the $\sigma$-algebra associated to the measure space. When we extend the measure $\mu_{0}$ on $\mathcal{A}$ to a measure on $\mathcal{M}^{*}(\mathcal{A})$, this is a complete measure, as states Caratheodory. The $\sigma$-algebra generated by $\mathcal{A}$, say $\mathcal{M}(\mathcal{A})$ is contained in $\mathcal{M}^{*}(\mathcal{A})$ but it can be strictly contained.

Comment: So, you don't know for sure if $\mathcal{M}(\mathcal{A})$ contains every null set. What you do know is that $\mathcal{M}^{*}(\mathcal{A})$ does. So, the restriction of $\mu$ to $\mathcal{M}(\mathcal{A})$ need not to be complete.

Comment: I think I might see now, I am thinking of it wrong. Let me see if this is correct: We know  is complete on M*(A) which means M*(A) contains all subsets of its null sets. M(A) may be contained in M*(A), but a null set of M(A) may have a subset which is contained in [M*(A)-M(A)]?